# Auto-formatting embed JavaScript in php files in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse, autoformatting, wildwebdeveloper

Why auto-formatting (by Ctrl-Shift-F) of embed JavaScript inside php file is not working in my Eclipse? I mean formatting of the block like this:

```
//php code here
?>
<script type="text/javascript">function test(){
console log( a);
        console.log('b');}
</script>
}
<?php
//php code here
```

I have Eclipse for PHP 2021-06 and WildWebDeveloper installed. If I put the same javascript code inside .js file JavaScript autoformatting works as expected.